# Restricting access to /rss not working NGINX

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, nginx

My Magento install keeps getting bombarded with traffic to `/rss/catalog/notifystock` which I read is a security issue in my current version of Magento.

This is causing to many concurrent sessions and therefore slowing the site right down or eventually taking it offline until they stop.

As a quick fix to combat this I wanted to deny all access to the `/rss`directory but alas my code doesn't **snippet** doesn't seem to have the desired affect and the url is still accessible.

I am using:

```
    location ~ /\rss* {
    # deny access to rss directory
    deny        all;
}
```

I though I may have incorrectly added this replacing rss  **with media** for example does stop access to the media directory.

Any thoughs on why this could be and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot Magento version 1.9.1.0 running on debian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I recall the RSS doesn't have a leading slash. Index.phprss/catalog/notifystock

Try this

```
location ~ rss/catalog/(review|notifystock) {
  allow x.x.x.x;
  deny all;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    echo_exec @phpfpm;
  }
}
```

Where x.x.x.x is your ip address

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly the code I was looking for :)